# Applying the definition of convergence for a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

There are many proofs that use $N = \max\{\dots , \dots  \}$ for the choice of $N$. For example if we want to prove $a_n = \frac{\sin 1}{2} + \frac{\sin 2}{2^2} + \dots \frac{\sin n}{2^n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, we let $N = \max\{\lfloor\ln(1/\epsilon)/\ln2 \rfloor + 1, 1\} $. Why this happens sometimes in the proofs? Is it always necessary? If not, when we should choose maximum for $N$? I think it has something to do with different cases for $\epsilon$.

Comment: Easy to show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=\frac{2\sin1}{5-4\cos1},$ which says that it's a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That's right but I want to understand why we use maximum for $N$.